# can't create SQL DataBase using Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create table permission denied in database ‘master’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313103/create-table-permission-denied-in-database-master)

I'm trying to create an SQL database by using Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010.

```
Server Explorer >> Data Connection >> Create new Sql Server Database
```

But when I'm trying to create the database it gives the error message

> > CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

I think it's about access privileges. I've searched quite a bit but can't find a solution.

Comment: Vist this link[http://stackoverflow.com/a/7313168/1954783]
It worked like a charm. Just need to download a small script and it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yup You've guessed it right it is a problem relating to your credentials being used to create the database (which in fact does not have access in your case )

Dariusz Parys have given a nice Fix to your problem [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx)